# For what values of $n$ in $[0,1]$ is $(\cos(x))^{n}>\cos(nx)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

For what values of $n$ in $[0,1]$ is $(\cos(x))^{n}>\cos(nx)$ ?

Is there any standard method for this type of problem?

Should I use calculus and define a function $h(x)$ as the  difference of the two functions and differentiate? But that method seems too long and tedious.

Is any alternate way possible?

Okay I found out its more easy than I thought

[I plotted a graph here on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bhgjxbpg3k)

Now I can see the thing clearly.Thanks to all those who answered.

Comment: Sum?  What sum?  And what is $x$?  You'd better have $\cos(x) \ge 0$ if you want the left side to be real.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if Taylor expansion could come in use here.

Comment: Sum is synonymous with mathematical problem(in my country atleast). @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$, $\cos(x)^n$ is a positive, convex function of $n$ on $[0,1]$, while $\cos(nx)$ is strictly concave.  Both are equal to $1$ when $n=0$ and $\cos(x)$ when $n=1$.  Therefore $\cos(x)^n < \cos(nx)$ for all $n \in (0,1)$.

It's more complicated if $x$ is not in this interval (of course we want $\cos(x) \ge 0$ for the left side to be real).

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1